# В каких случаях можно применять | или &| или & в качестве логических операторов

Tags: c#, if, условия, логические-выражения

Когда нужно, чтобы выполнились оба операнда или функции? Например:

```
if(func1() | func2())
```

Вопрос в том, на практике встречали ли вы такое применение, и разумно ли оно?

Или проще отдельно вызвать функцию в блоке `if`, а не в условии?

Comment: вы путаете условные операторы и побитовые. `||` - условный, `|` - побитовый. Везде, где вам надо преверять условия, например, `if (A || B)` - используете условный оператор. Везде, где вам надо применять побитовый, например `var flags = flagA | flagB;` - применяйте побитовые.

Comment: @tym32167 Это не совсем побитовые операторы, для булевых значений это логические операторы _без_ короткого замыкания

Comment: @NowhereMan называйте как хотите, мой поинт в том, что и когда использовать - для каждого случая надо использовать свой инструмент.  `|` - вот это для булевых значений ведет себя именно как побитовый оператор, независимо от того, что там оно под капотом делает.

Comment: @NowhereMan, всё таки побитовые. Просто для булевых переменных результат по счастливой случайности совпадает с логическими.

Comment: Короткий ответ: ни в каких.

Comment: @aepot лучший ответ на самом деле, но пусть уж висит и длинный =)

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим все подвопросы отдельно:

***1. В каких случаях можно применять `|` или `&|` или `&` в качестве логических операторов,

Когда нужно, чтобы выполнились оба операнда или функции?***

Во-первых, оператора `&|` НЕ существует.

Во-вторых, операторы без короткого замыкания `|` или `&` *можно* применять, когда *нужно*, чтобы *обязательно* выполнились оба операнда или функции_ -- такая возможность предоставляется во всех основных языках программирования (C#, [Java/Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540718/), [Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534981/), [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487067/), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281469/)).

Данный момент как раз объясняется в стандартной документации, при условии, что функции `func1()` и `func2()` возвращают булевые значения:

> **[Оператор логического И &](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators?redirectedfrom=MSDN#logical-and-operator-)**
> Оператор `&` вычисляет логическое И для всех своих операндов. Результат операции `x & y` принимает значение `true`, если оба оператора `x` и `y` имеют значение `true`. В противном случае результат будет `false`.
>
> Оператор `&` вычисляет оба операнда, даже если левый операнд имеет значение `false`. При этом операция должна вернуть значение `false`, независимо от значения правого операнда.

> **[Оператор логического ИЛИ |](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators?redirectedfrom=MSDN#logical-or-operator-)**
> Оператор `|` вычисляет логическое ИЛИ для всех своих операндов. Результат операции `x | y` принимает значение `true`, если хотя бы один из операторов `x` или `y` имеет значение `true`. В противном случае результат будет `false`.
>
> Оператор `|` вычисляет оба операнда, даже если левый операнд имеет значение `true`. При этом операция должна вернуть значение `true`, независимо от значения правого операнда.

В-третьих, следует различать обработку булевых констант (очень быструю) и вызовы функций в условиях (потенциально, *очень* медленные).

В любом случае, если такой нестандартный способ позволил реализовать нужную логику, она должна быть задокументирована / откомментирована и покрыта соответствующими тестами.

---

***2. Вопрос в том, на практике встречали ли вы такое применение, и разумно ли оно?***

Нет, такое применение НЕ рекомендуется и встречается не часто.
Как правило, в подавляющем большинстве случаев оно вызвано опечаткой / небрежностью, затем выше вероятность плохого дизайна / небезопасного кода (особенно при вызове функций прямо в условии), и лишь при определённых повышенных требованиях к производительности *и* использовании константных операндов такое применение может быть оправдано.

В частности, статический анализатор CodeQL содержит особое правило для такого кода [Potentially dangerous use of non-short-circuit logic](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/csharp/cs-non-short-circuit/), согласно которого логические операции БЕЗ короткого замыкания считаются ошибкой.

Сама необходимость такого кода достаточно спорный вопрос, так как подразумевается, что функции `func1`, `func2` имеют некие побочные эффекты и важно, чтобы `func2` выполнялась *всегда*.

Примером побочного эффекта может быть обычное логирование как показано в [ответе на подобный вопрос на основном SO: "Short circuit vs non short circuit operators"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18349426/13279831).

Другой *надуманный* пример, когда необходимо, чтобы выполнились обе функции -- проверка пароля и увеличение счётчика попыток ввода:

```cs
while (!password.isValid() & ++attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
    // ввести пароль заново
}
```

хотя и его можно переписать с оператором `&&`, изменив порядок в условии

```cs
while (++attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS && !password.isValid()) {
    // ввести пароль заново
}
```

Поэтому на практике предпочтение отдаётся *более разумным* операциям с коротким замыканием `&&`, `||`, именно потому, что они позволяют избежать ненужных вычислений / вызовов функций и в целом делают код понятнее.

Кроме того, эффекта *обязательного выполнения обеих частей условия* возможно достичь и при помощи условных операторов с коротким замыканием [И `&&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators?redirectedfrom=MSDN#conditional-logical-and-operator-) [ИЛИ `||`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators?redirectedfrom=MSDN#conditional-logical-or-operator-), если результаты операций вычисляются заранее и присваиваются отдельным переменным:

```cs
bool foo = func1();
bool bar = func2();
if (foo && bar) {        // аналог if (func1() & func2())
    // ...
} else if (foo || bar) { // аналог if (func1() | func2())

    // ...
}
```

Достаточно редкий случай, когда применение операторов `|`, `&` может быть оправдано в условных операторах -- нано-оптимизация, так как в случае некоторого числа *константных* операндов (не функций!), результат может быть вычислен быстрее (за гарантированное время) *без короткого замыкания*, так как для коротко-замкнутых операторов `||`, `&&` создаётся много *лишних* ветвлений.

Ссылки на основной SO:

- [Short Circuiting and Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020855/)
- [Is "IF" expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315306/)
- [Why short circuit logical operator is supposed to be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983234/)

---

***3. Или проще отдельно вызвать функцию в блоке `if`, а не в условии?***

Нет, не проще, -- если вызывать функцию в блоке, то получится код вида `if (func1()) { if (func2()) {...}}`, имеющий совершенно другую логику с И: `if (func1() && func2())`, а не первоначальным ИЛИ.
Вероятно, *проще* было бы проверять результаты выполнения обеих функций независимо друг от друга в двух операторах `if`, но это также подразумевает рефакторинг первоначальной логики.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно, чтобы выполнялись оба операнда, пишите это в явном виде и потом проверяйте с использованием логического или:

```
var res1 = func1();
var res2 = func2();
if(res1 || res2)
...
```

Вернее даже не так. Лучше разделять методы, которые Что-то делают и которые возвращают какой-то статус. Если вам нужно точно что-то сделать, то и делайте в методе, который производит работу. А состояние проверяйте другим методом:

```
DoSomething1();
DoSomething2();
if(IsSomeState1() || IsSomeState2())
...
```

Возможно, это вообще должны быть методы объектов 1 и 2. Тут можно до бесконечности рефакторить. Главное - делайте лучше явно всё, а не так, что читающему код нужно будет задумываться как же оно работает.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле хороший вопрос, не смотря на то, что у знатоков в программировании вообще и C# в частности он обычно не возникает.

Если мы говорим о логических операциях, то из определения операций И(AND) и ИЛИ(OR) в алгебре логики следует отсутствие необходимости вычисления второго операнда в случае, когда значение первого операнда дает однозначный ответ.

> Определение.
> Логическая функция MIN в двухзначной (двоичной) логике называется конъюнкция (логическое «И», логическое умножение или просто «И»).
> Правило: результат равен наименьшему операнду.

> Определение.
> Логическая функция MAX в двухзначной (двоичной) логике называется дизъюнкция (логическое «ИЛИ», логическое сложение или просто «ИЛИ»).
> Правило: результат равен наибольшему операнду.

Минимум и максимум для одного бита в двоичной логике всегда однозначно определены и никаких промежуточных значений быть не может, следовательно необходимость вычисления второго операнда определяется исключительно значением первого.

Как дела обстоят в C#:

- Выделен отдельный тип данных `System.Boolean` или `bool`, что одно и то же, который предназначен для использования в условных операторах или условиях в циклах. Это хорошо, так как не требует особых конвенций для условий как, например, в C/C++ принято считать истиной любое значение отличное от нуля, и позволяет избежать ошибок при проверке чего либо на равенство выполнив вместо этого присваивание, как во все тех же C/C++, где эта ошибка довольно сильно распространена.
- Есть логические операторы, которые всегда возвращают значения типа `bool`: `&&`(И), `||`(ИЛИ), `!`(НЕ). Эти операторы, работают согласно требованиям алгебры логики и позволяют не вычислять значение второго операнда, когда в этом нет необходимости. Разумеется для унарной операции `!`(НЕ) второй операнд не вычисляется в виду его отсутствия
- Есть операторы "двойного назначения": `&`(AND),`|`(OR),`^`(XOR), которые, следуя логике документации, при использовании с типом `bool` ведут себя как логические, а с целочисленными типами и производными от них - как битовые. Но это не совсем верно, т.к. **по сути** тип `bool` также является целочисленным типом длиной в один бит с двумя доступными значениями 0 и 1 и к нему также применяются правила битовой арифметики, которые не зависят от количества значащих бит в операндах и требуют значения обоих операндов для вычисления результата. Вся разница при использовании с типом `bool` и другими допустимыми типами заключается в финальном преобразовании типа результата.

Что касается использования в C# коде операций `&` и `|` в условных операторах для принудительного вычисления второго операнда с каким-то побочным эффектом, то их использование может быть обусловлено только экономией строк кода программы с потерей читаемости кода и усложнением дальнейшей отладки и сопровождения. Никакой другой практической ценности подобное не содержит и это сложно назвать "ценностью", скорее наоборот

PS: да я читал и документацию, и спеки, и даже в исходники библиотек .NET лазил своими немытыми лапами. Я не считаю, что было правильным идти по пути слепого копирования синтаксиса C/C++ и смешивать в кучу логические и битовые операции при наличии отдельного логического типа данных, но это цена синтаксической узнаваемости между всеми C-подобными языками, так что имеем что имеем